# QEMU 5.2 on Windows host: error “Property 'pc-q35-5.2-machine.i8042' not found”

Tags: windows-11, qemu, hardware-acceleration, hardware-virtualization

I have a QEMU VM that I need to run on different host machines. I runs fine on a macOS host with hardware acceleration (`-accel hvf`).

While Hyper-V runs fine on my Windows 11 host (e.g., I can setup and run an instance with a Linux guest), QEMU 8 with `-accel whpx` errors with:

```
qemu: WHPX: Failed to emulate MMIO access with EmulatorReturnStatus: 2
qemu: WHPX: Failed to exec a virtual processor
```

According to https://www.reddit.com/r/VFIO/comments/l9bl8b/comment/h0bdxib/, WHPX in QEMU is broken after version 5.2 (qemu-w64-setup-20210208.exe from https://qemu.weilnetz.de/w64/2021/). Looking at the full reddit thread, some posters fixed it using `-accel whpx,kernel-irqchip=off`. However, this doesn’t change a thing for me. I still get the same error message.

Now, after reverting to QEMU 5.2, it errors out with:

```
C:\Program Files\qemu\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: Property 'pc-q35-5.2-machine.i8042' not found
```

My full command is:

```
"C:\Program Files\qemu\qemu-system-x86_64.exe" ^
-L "C:\Program Files\qemu" ^
-nodefaults ^
-vga none ^
-device e1000,mac=0A:AD:47:06:D2:2C,netdev=net0 ^
-netdev user,id=net0 ^
-device vmware-svga ^
-cpu Penryn,+sse4.1,+sse4.2,+ssse3 ^
-smp cpus=1,sockets=1,cores=1,threads=1 ^
-machine q35,vmport=off,i8042=off,hpet=off ^
-accel whpx ^
-global ICH9-LPC.disable_s3=1 ^
-drive "if=pflash,format=raw,unit=0,file.filename=C:\Program Files\qemu\edk2-x86_64-code.fd,file.locking=off,readonly=on" ^
-drive "if=pflash,unit=1,file=C:\Users\boe\Documents\mabam\Drives\efi_vars.fd" ^
-m 4096 ^
-usb ^
-device usb-tablet,bus=usb-bus.0 ^
-device usb-mouse,bus=usb-bus.0 ^
-device usb-kbd,bus=usb-bus.0 ^
-device nec-usb-xhci,id=usb-controller-0 ^
-device ide-hd,bus=ide.0,drive=EFI,bootindex=0 ^
-drive "if=none,media=disk,id=EFI,file=C:\Users\boe\Documents\mabam\Drives\efi.qcow2,discard=unmap,detect-zeroes=unmap" ^
-device ide-hd,bus=ide.1,drive=SLHD,bootindex=1 ^
-drive "if=none,media=disk,id=SLHD,file=C:\Users\boe\Documents\mabam\Drives\SystemHDD.qcow2,discard=unmap,detect-zeroes=unmap" ^
-device virtio-rng-pci
```

On QEMU 8 (after changing line 2 to `-L "C:\Program Files\qemu\share" ^`, adding `\share` to the edk2-x86_64-code.fd directory and removing `-accel whpx ^`), it starts and runs fine, even if I use `-machine pc-q35-5.2` i.s.o. `-machine q35` to verify backward compatibility of my VM image. Only it’s dead slow as it lacks acceleration and is therefore unusable.

**As QEMU 5.2 seems to be my only chance, how can I fix the following error (as already written above)?**

```
C:\Program Files\qemu\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: Property 'pc-q35-5.2-machine.i8042' not found
```